# SQL IN clause which is guaranteed to evaluate to false

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-in

Is there any value which I can place in a SQL IN clause which will guarantee that the clause will evaluate to false?

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID IN (???)
```

Is there anything I could replace ??? with to guarantee no rows will be returned?

Comment: What datatype is ProductID ?

Comment: A numeric value but not an integer, 1.23?

Comment: @Matt Assume it's an int

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace with `NULL`. There is no better guarantee!

Because no other value can equal to `NULL`, even `NULL` itself.

And this is kinda universal value for any type(as @zohar-peled mentioned).

Comment: had the same thought. beat me to it :) + 1

Comment: Beat me to it! `IN (NULL)` will never match, not even to `NULL`

Comment: 1 second faster then me :-)

Comment: Ahh to fast for me :)!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is this safe with `NOT IN` too?

Comment: @IanNewson, absolutely, predicate will evaluate to `UNKNOWN` in both cases and filter out all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID IN (NULL)
```

As this will return nothing

Answer (score -1):

Put some initially invalid ProductID, e.g. `-1`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID IN (-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID IN (0)
```

I'm pretty sure that you don`t have product with ID=0

That will return false.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT '')
```

Another possible way.

Comment: `SELECT ''` will be implicitly cast to `0`, which I can't accept.